# Short story, 19th century: French country priest and devil exchange subjectivities

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, french-language, guy-de-maupassant

I am looking for a 19th century short story. I thought it was written by Guy de Maupassant, but didn't find it. A French country priest starts having vivid dreams that he is a diabolical courtier in hell. The dreams become ever more intense and elaborated. The last line is something like: "One night, one of the devil's courtier's had a strange dream, that he was a French country priest." The basic idea seems to be borrowed from Zhuangzi's 'The Butterfly Dream'.

Comment: Did you read the story in French (I'm assuming it was originally written in French; that's the meaning of the [[tag:french-literature]] tag) or as an English translation? When did you read it? Where? In a collection? If so, can you remember anything else about the collection? See our [identification-request tag wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for more kinds of helpful information to include. If anything jogs your memory, please [edit] in more details.

Comment: Vaguely reminiscent of [*La Morte Amoureuse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Morte_Amoureuse) by Théophile Gautier.